# Aside from $\langle 0 \rangle$, can a ring of algebraic integers have prime ideals that are not maximal?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, ideals

I have a feeling that a ring with such ideals would have to be non-UFD, and I can prove that in $\mathbb{Z}$ there are no such ideals. But in other rings, I'm not so sure. I'm not yet at a point at which I understand ideals in rings of polynomials, though I have seen a couple of examples of non-maximal prime ideals in such rings.

Comment: There are non-maximal prime ideals in UFD's. If not, this ring will be a PID (if it's already a UFD). So you will find always such ideal if the ring is not a PID and is a UFD.

Answer (score 4):

No. If $\mathcal{O}_K$ is a ring of integers and $P$ is a nonzero prime ideal, then $\mathcal{O}_K/P$ is a finite integral domain, and by [Wedderburn's little theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wedderburn%27s_little_theorem) it must be a field. More generally, Dedekind domains have Krull dimension $1$, which means that if $D$ is a Dedekind domain and $P$ is a nonzero prime ideal then $D/P$ has no nontrivial prime ideals, hence is a field.